# jad and jar size do not match in j2me

Tags: mobile, java-me, midp, jad

I am using N97 and Nokia 5530 for my application. More often whenever I install my application. I find this error. I have searched the internet and found a number of ways to solve this problem. I did use them such as check size of jar and the one written in jad and corrected it but still problem is not solved.

How can I remove this error in my build. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

I have read the stuff--- [Unification of .jar and .jad files in a J2ME application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869288/unification-of-jar-and-jad-files-in-a-j2me-application) --- but today devices and internet are much faster. Can't we ignore the creation of jad file.

---

EDIT

Following are jad and manifest attributes. I am using NetBeans 6.9 and Nokia S60 5th Edition SDK to generate and build the MIDlet.

jad attributes are as follows

`Backkey: -11

LGE-MIDlet-Height: 400

LGE-MIDlet-Target-LCD-Height: 400

LGE-MIDlet-Target-LCD-Width: 240

LGE-MIDlet-Width: 240

LeftSoftKey: -6

MIDlet-1: MyAppName,/icon.png,com.main.MainMidlet

MIDlet-Jar-Size: 964642

MIDlet-Jar-URL: MyAppName.jar

MIDlet-Name: MyAppName

MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.Connector.http

MIDlet-Touch-Support: true

MIDlet-Vendor: www.MyApp.com

MIDlet-Version: 1.4

MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1

MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0

Navi-Key-Hidden: true

Nokia-MIDlet-App-Orientation: portrait

Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no

RightSoftKey: -7

UseNativeTextButton: true`

and Manifest attributes are

`Manifest-Version: 1.0

Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.0

Created-By: 1.6.0_21-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

MIDlet-1: MyAppName,/icon.png,com.main.MainMidlet

MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.Connector.http

MIDlet-Vendor: www.MyApp.com

Nokia-MIDlet-App-Orientation: portrait

LGE-MIDlet-Height: 400

Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no

MIDlet-Name: MyAppName

Navi-Key-Hidden: true

MIDlet-Touch-Support: true

LGE-MIDlet-Width: 240

MIDlet-Version: 1.4

Backkey: -11

LeftSoftKey: -6

UseNativeTextButton: true

LGE-MIDlet-Target-LCD-Height: 400

RightSoftKey: -7

LGE-MIDlet-Target-LCD-Width: 240

MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1

MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0`

Comment: post the jad, the manifest, the size of the jar and describe how you generate and build the MIDlet

Comment: I have edited my comment, Please have a view of it and suggest me suggest me what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that I usually see `MIDlet-Jar-Size` in the manifest, not in the jad.

Unfortunately, I never figured out how the build system managed to insert it in a compressed file (jars are basically zip files) and I don't know how to tell Netbeans to move the property from the jad to the manifest.

I was under the impression that if you ask Netbeans to generate a simple HelloWorld MIDlet and don't modify the ant script, `MIDlet-Jar-Size` ends up in the manifest.

I do think there is a relation between the property and the MIDlet being signed. It may act as a checksum.